# Promise.join not working with arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluebird

I have been working on a function that returns all of the values of several database tables. I am trying to proactively adopt stable es6 features and this seemed like a good opportunity for arrow functions. I am using bluebird for promises and sequelize as my ORM (which returns bluebird promises for their DB queries)

```
/**
 * This does not work on node v4.2.0
 */
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird');
const models = require('../database');

const resource = {
    browse: function browse() {
        return Promise.join(
            () => models.table_one.findAll(),
            () => models.table_two.findAll(),
            () => models.table_three.findAll(),
            function(table_one, table_two, table_three) {
                const response = {
                    table_one,
                    table_two,
                    table_three,
                };

                return response;
            });
    },
};

module.exports = resource;
```

This doesn't work

```
/**
 * But this does
 */
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird');
const models = require('../database');

const resource = {
    browse: function browse() {
        function getTableOne() {
            return models.table_one.findAll();
        }

        function getTableTwo() {
            return models.table_two.findAll();
        }

        function getTableThree() {
            return models.table_three.findAll();
        }
        return Promise.join(
                getTableOne(),
                getTableTwo(),
                getTableThree(),
                function(table_one, table_two, table_three) {
                    const response = {
                        table_one,
                        table_two,
                        table_three,
                    };

                    return response;
                });
    },
};

module.exports = resource;
```

I have also tried wrapping the calls to models in curling brackets and explicitly returning them. This isn't a huge priority since I have a work-around, but I would like the gain a better understanding of the newest features. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Promise.join` expects one or more **promises**, not functions.

```
Promise.join(getTableOne(), ...)
```

**calls** `getTableOne` and passes the return value, a promise, to `Promise.join`.

But

```
Promise.join(() => models.table_one.findAll(), ...)
```

passes the function itself to `Promise.join`, *not* a promise. It does *not* call the function.

There is no need for an arrow function here:

```
Promise.join(models.table_one.findAll(), ...)
```

Comment: Not that this would be best practice but would the following technically work iife:
    Promise.join((() => models.table_one.findAll())(), ...)